# Order by relational STAT in yii

Tags: php, yii, relationship

I'm using yii framework. I have a relation

```
'revCount'=>array(self::STAT, 'Review','rid','condition'=>'status=1')//count review for each restaurant
```

Now I want to fetch all Restaurants order by review count.

```
Restaurant::model()->findAll('with'=>'revCount');
```

What else I need to add so that I get all restaurants ordered by review count?

Comment: did u try 
Restaurant::model()->findAll('with'=>'revCount', 'order' => 'revCount'); 
Does it work ?

Comment: no. It says that column 'revCount' doesnot exist

Answer (score 1):

This is how you join other models with a single query:

```
Restaurant::model()->with('revCount')->findAll();
```

But what I think you want is not to join the model, but just to sort by it. Similar to this:

```
Restaurant::model()->with(array(
    'reviews'=>array(
        // we don't want to select reviews
        'select'=>false,
        // but want to get only reviews with status=1
        'joinType'=>'INNER JOIN',
        'condition'=>'reviews.status=1',
    ),
))->findAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do the following..

```
Restaurant::model()->findAll('with'=>'revCount', 'select' => '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM review WHERE rid = t.id AND status = 1) AS revCount');
```